# Specifying datasource in standalone-full-ha.xml in jboss 6.3

Tags: java, database, jdbc, deployment, jboss

Am using Jboss 6.3. We were deploying our application by specifying the datasource in standalone.xml file and it was working fine. But now we have to put the datasource details in standalone-full-ha.xml and make it work. I simply copied the datasource subsytem part from standalone.xml to standalone-full-ha.xml but this is not working and our deployment is failing. Can someone tell me what am doing wrong here? Is there any other additional settings I have to maintain for this to work? Java version is 1.7 and am using scientific linux on a server and operating it via putty.

Comment: In general that should work. You need to provide more details about your error

Comment: Sorry for the confusion regarding this. The problem was because while starting the sever it was still referring to standalone.xml instead of standalone-full-ha.xml. Solved by using sh standalone.sh --server-config=standalone-full-ha.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because while starting the sever it was still referring to standalone.xml instead of standalone-full-ha.xml. Solved by using sh standalone.sh --server-config=standalone-full-ha.xml